# Mac "other" storage super hidden

Tags: storage

I've looked through quite a few other posts about this issue and they always seem to get resolved by some iTunes or document storage that the Mac is accidentally tracking as part of the "other" storage. But my Mac has no files on it except for System files and Steam.
I used it a long time ago but wiped everything clean, now there's 87GB of other files somewhere? I don't see them in any directory, DiskDaisy shows them as in hidden hidden space, but I don't have the money to pay for DiskDaisy to do Admin Scan. I just want to be able to use my Mac again lol.

No TimeMachine, no caches that I can find, I've tried quite a few things so far

[image: Storage Image]

I'll continue looking while I wait to see if this gets any responses, getting frustrated here :/

Comment: In the Terminal utility, run `df -h` to see how much space is listed in the Used column for the volumes "/" (core system files), "/System/Volumes/Data" (almost everything else), and "/private/var/vm" (virtual memory). Do those add up to the roughly 105GB used? If not, open Disk Utility, choose View menu > Show All Devices, select the container on the left column, and see what volumes it lists and how much space they use.

Comment: Here are the results from df -h, it looks like System/Volumes/Data is taking up the vast majority, not sure what that means exactly, I'm pretty new to Mac, been on PC for ages. OmniDiskSweeper didn't show anything new either, In response to the other answer. 

https://i.imgur.com/LzETH9o.png

Comment: Ok, that eliminates some of the possibilities for where all the space is going. Next, make sure [Terminal has Full Disk Access](https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/), then run `sudo du -hxd1 /System/Volumes/Data` (it'll ask for your admin password; it won't echo anything as you type). That'll probably still get some errors, but hopefully it'll be able to show which subfolder is huge. If necessary, you can run e.g. `sudo du -hxd1 /System/Volumes/bigfolder` to narrow it down further.

Comment: Solved! You are my hero! I went down the rabbit hole of folders that was /Data/private and found a bunch of miscellaneous files I used to have but at some point got rid of, for some reason they were all saved o.O. Gone now though! https://i.imgur.com/IAceA2Q.png I hereby reclaim my MacBook! Thanks a ton Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Omni Disk Sweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) which will tell you exactly what files, even hidden ones, are taking up extra storage on your Mac